# bitwise operation on string representation of binary number python 2.7

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I would like to perform a bitwise OR on two string representations of binary numbers, but I can't figure out how to convert the strings into raw binary.

a = '010110'
b = '100000'

a | b

should yield:
110110

I then want to count the number of on bits.
This should return:
4

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the strings to binary using the built-in [int() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) and passing 2 as the base:

```
a = int('010110', 2)
b = int('100000', 2)
```

then OR the two values and count the bits by converting to a string and counting the "1" characters:

```
print bin(a | b).count("1")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom class derived from `str` and override its magic method responsible for the binary OR operator `|`.

There are many ways to implement the OR. The probably easiest one was already described by [@samgak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696391/samgak) in his answer, you can use `int` with specifying the base number as 2 and then use its `|` operator:

```
class bitstr(str)
    def __or__(self, other):
        return bin(int(self, 2) | int(other, 2))[2:]
        # need to slice because 'bin' prefixes the result string with "0b".
```

This is how you could use it:

```
a = '010110'
b = bitstr('100000')

print(bitstr(a) | b)
# Output: 110110
```

You see that you need a conversion to `bitstr` somewhere, but it does not matter at which point. Also, for all other operations except the `|` operator, our custom `bitstr` behaves exactly like a normal `str` string, so you could use that everywhere if you want.

[See this code running on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/eYrYCO)