# Bitwise operation on Binary string python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitwise-operators

If I have two strings of binary representation. How to do bitwise on them?

Example

```
a = '101'
b = '010'
c = a | b
c => '111'
```

Comment: 1. Parse them as ints (in binary). 2. Perform `|` operation. 3. Convert result to string. (4. Profit.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bitwise operation on string representation of binary number python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37201413/bitwise-operation-on-string-representation-of-binary-number-python-2-7)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373554/logical-or-for-bit-string-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logical OR for Bit-string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373554/logical-or-for-bit-string-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `int` to convert the binary strings to numbers. You can use the [second parameter of `int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to specify the base, 2 in this case. Then, you can use `|` to "or" the numbers and [`bin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) or a format-string (many different possibilities here) to convert back to binary.

```
>>> a = '101'
>>> b = '010'
>>> c = int(a, 2) | int(b, 2)
>>> bin(c)
'0b111'
>>> f"{c:b}"
'111'
>>> format(c, "b")
'111'
```

The latter two can also be used to add any number of leading zeros, if necessary, e.g. using `08b` instead of `b` in the format string.

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' Then you are using an older version of Python. Use the ones that do not give an error.

Comment: Removes leading zeros, though, for example `'010'` and `'001'` turn into `'11'` instead of `'011'`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that works on the strings (not via ints) and keeps leading zeros intact:

```
>>> a = '0101'
>>> b = '0011'
>>> ''.join(map(max, a, b))
'0111'
```

Needs the strings to have equal length, but given your example where one string has a leading zero so it's as long as the other, I guess that's the case for you.

Comment: Neat... but you might add a note that both strings have to be the same length.

Comment: Hmm, since the OP's example is `'101'` and `'010'`, not `'10'`, I believe their strings do have the same length.